# Slow spinup of Maxtor Basics Desktop USB external hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, spinup

(Posting on behalf of a friend who has this problem.)

I have got a 500 GB [**Maxtor Basics Desktop**](http://www.maxtor.com/gb/hard-drive-backup/external-drives/basics_desktop.html) USB external hard drive, and I have one annoying issue with it. It goes to **sleep** mode way too early and it has a very **slow spin-up** when returning from sleep mode.

I have not really timed it, but I think it enters sleep mode after about 10-20 minutes of inactivity.  When Windows needed to access the disk, it would take about 10 seconds to spin up -- and that would halt other things (like Windows Explorer) in the process. Even when I am not using the Maxtor, sometimes Windows still needs to poll the disk (such as when an **Open File** dialog starts listing files at **My Computer** which would also probe the external disk), and this slow-down from the Maxtor halts everything until it finishes spinning up.

I have tried to find a way to change the configuration of the Maxtor drive, but I could not find any. I have not found any utility for Maxtor Basics Desktop external hard drive either.

Do you have any idea how I can remedy this -- like setting time to sleep to some longer time, or a way to shorten the spin-up time?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to change the sleep timer to a longer time, up to 5 hours, or never at all.  Check out [Maxtor OneTouch 4 Lite software](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=ot4-downloads&vgnextoid=0ed72c9e46914110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD).  Although it's supposed to be used for Maxtor OneTouch, it does recognize Maxtor Basics and can change its sleep timer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to change this. I have a 250GB external drive that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to speed up the drive spinup, but you can write a script that polls the hard drive every 5 minutes. It's not a pretty solution, but it will prevent the drive from spinning down. This will shorten the life of the drive and increase your power consumption.